# Can I boot with an old system on a new pc?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moving the Windows 7 hard disk from one machine to another](https://superuser.com/questions/86755/moving-the-windows-7-hard-disk-from-one-machine-to-another)

I have update the hardware of my pc execpt my hard disk, and it have the old windows 7 and ubuntu on it. Can I boot with the old windows 7 without reinstalling it?

Comment: you can try :-)  Depending on the ammount of drivers that will be different it would be a total mess, even if you get past the minor activations issues.

Comment: Try booting in safe-mode first.

Comment: Please post a list of old vs new critical hardware in order to get a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Odds are no. When you install windows, it loads drivers for all the hardware it detects during the install. The critical parts are the motherboard chipset and disk. If those are the same (including how you are accessing the harddrive - for example the SATA access mode), it would get you bootable to the point of then needing to update the different hardware (everything with question marks in your device manager). 
The other problem is the windows license. It might complain if for example the previous motherboard was an HP (with a HP-Windows license based on the bios) and the new motherboard is a dell.