# Can I directly use a Windows 10 SSD disk from a desktop in a laptop?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, operating-systems

I have a 2.5" SSD disk on my old desktop. Windows 10 is installed on it. I also have a newer laptop with an HDD disk. I am thinking to unplug the SSD disk from the desktop and plug it into the laptop to replace the HDD disk. I am wondering do I need to reinstall the Windows 10 OS. Can the Windows on that SSD work on the laptop directly?

Comment: “Can the Windows on that SSD work on the laptop directly?” I am mainly a macOS and Linux person, but I believe modern Windows ties the OS installation to the motherboard in some way. Like some kind of hardware check to prevent doing what you are suggesting to do. But like I said, Windows is not my think. Someone else will come along and provide more accurate details.

Comment: The answers in the link aren't quite correct.  I deleted my answer there as it got voted down.  As @Giacomo1968 says, windows is locked in using a hardware signature from your PC.  Once you get it booting, it will be Deactivated and you have to **Activate** it again.  So, if your intention is piracy, it may not work.  I recently changed my motherboard and that's what happened.  If you change just the graphics card, as an example, it generally carries on working as the change is not "Substantial", quote from MS, some years ago.

Comment: @RohitGupta “I deleted my answer there as it got voted down.” What? I have high enough rep to see deleted answers and I [don’t see anything posted by you there](https://superuser.com/q/86755/167207) let alone something that was voted down.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - you are quite right, it was a similar question, but not this one.